# Matching The Arabic punctuation marks in Java

Tags: java, regex, arabic

I want to edit on REGEX_PATTERN2 in this code to work with matches()method of The Arabic punctuation marks

```
 String REGEX_PATTERN = "[\\.|,|:|;|!|_|\\?]+";
        String s1 = "My life :is happy, stable";
        String[] result = s1.split(REGEX_PATTERN);
        for (String myString : result) {
            System.out.println(myString);   

}

         String REGEX_PATTERN2 = "[\\.|,|:|;|!|_|،|؛|؟\\?]+";
            String s2 = " حياتي ؛ سعيدة، مستقر";
            String[] result2 = s2.split(REGEX_PATTERN2);
            for (String myString : result2) {
                System.out.println(myString);   

    }
```

The output I wanted

My life

is happy

stable

حياتي

سعيدة

مستقر

How I can edit to this code and use the **matches()** instead of **split()** method   to get the same output with Arabic punctuation marks

Comment: Are the ... a single character or three?

Comment: *"It works with English perfect but with Arabic not work."* - It would help if you provides examples of it not working in Arabic text.  *In the question!*

Comment: You are missing the point.  I want you to give us a clear example of Arabic text for which your Arabic punctuation regex doesn't work.

Comment: I add  example of Arabic text

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems here.  First this example:

```
  if (word.matches("[\\.|,|:|;|!|\\?]+"))
```

That is mildly<sup>1</sup> incorrect for the following reason:

1. A `.` does not need to be escaped in a character class.
2. A `|` does not mean alternation in a character class.
3. A `?` does not need to be escaped in a character class.

(For more details, read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or a tutorial on Java regexes.)

So you can rewrite the above as:

```
  if (word.matches("[.,:;!?]+"))
```

... assuming that you don't want to classify the pipe character as punctuation.

Now this:

```
 if (word.matches("[\.|,|:|;|!|،|؛|..|...|؟|\?]+"))
```

You have same problems as above.  In addition, you seem to have used the two and three full-stop / period characters instead of (presumably) some Unicode character.  I suspect they might be a `\ufbb7` or `u061e` or `\u06db`, but I'm no linguist.  (Certainly 2  or 3 full-stops is incorrect.)

---

So what *are* the punctuation characters in Arabic?

To be honest, I think that the answer depends on what source you look at, but Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Punctuation_and_ornaments):

> Only the Arabic question mark ⟨؟⟩ and the Arabic comma ⟨،⟩ are used in regular Arabic script typing and the comma is often substituted for the Latin script comma (,).

---

<sup>1 - By mildly incorrect, I mean that the mistakes in this example are mostly harmless.  However, your inclusion of (multiple instances of) the `|` character n the class does mean that you will incorrectly classify a "pipe" as punctuation.</sup>

Comment: but I need to use | character, it meaning OR

Comment: You don't need an "OR" in a character class.  The OR is implicit.  Please read the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.   Search the page for "Character classes" and look at the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` denotes a regex *character class*, which means it only matches single characters. `...` is 3 characters, so it cannot be used in a character class.

In a character class, you don't separate characters with `|`, and you don't need to escape `.` and `?`.

You probably meant this, which is a list of alternate character sequences:

`"(?:\\.|,|:|;|!|\\?|،|؛|؟|\\.\\.|\\.\\.\\.)+"`

You might get better performance if you do use a character class where you can:

`"(?:\\.{1,3}|[,:;!?،؛؟])+"`

Of course, with the `+` at the end, matching 1-3 periods in each iteration is rather redundant, so this will do:

`"[.,:;!?،؛؟]+"`

Comment: I am trying with this "(?:\\.{1,3}|[,:;!?،؛؟])+" it also good with English but with Arabic not work, so do you think import class UTF-8 ? in java

Comment: @salma Edit the question and show us an example of what doesn't work. [Simply saying "doesn't work" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: @salma If you're having issues with source file encoding, use Unicode escapes, e.g. instead of `"[.,:;!?،؛؟]+"`, write `"[.,:;!?\u060C\u061B\u061F]+"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach, that uses Unicode properties instead of specific characters (In case you care about more Arabic marks than just the question mark and comma mentioned in another answer):

```
"(?=^[\\p{InArabic}.,:;!?]+$)^\\p{IsPunctuation}+$"
```

It matches an entire string of characters that have a punctuation category, that also are either in the Arabic block or are one of the other punctuation characters you listed in your efforts.

It'll match strings like `"؟،"` or `"؟،:"`, but not `"؟،ؠ"` or `"؟،a"`.

Comment: but i need string like "؟،ؠ"

Comment: @salma So you want to match more than just punctuation? You should edit your question to be more explicit about what strings you're trying to match and what should be allowed or not.